# Ordering a column by popularity in an SQL join?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem where I need to display some data using a join. One of the columns must then be grouped by 'colour' as well as popularity (so the group of colours that appear most often will display as the first set of rows and so forth).

So far I have made the join and managed to group it by colour:

```
SELECT * FROM tblexample1 
JOIN tblexample2 ON tblexample1.unique_id = tblexample2.unique_id
ORDER BY colour;
```

I just need to get the same colour column organised by popularity, is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Help us help you - share the tables' structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for this sample.

Comment: What do you mean by "one of the columns must be grouped by..." - how do you suppose **one column** is grouped, while the other columns are not? There's no way to help you if you can't even present a meaningful requirement.

Comment: I'm betting he just wants something like `ORDER BY colour, popularity`

Comment: In my data I have information relating to vehicles, such as vehicle_id, model, total miles, and colour. Many different cars may have the same colour, such as blue. My table needs to be grouped so that all blue cars are displayed together in a group of rows and then all red cars are displayed together, etc (grouped by colour). If for example a blue car is present 20 times in the table and a red car only 10 times, I need the blue grouped cars to be shown first because they're the most popular (grouped by popularity of colour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY colour) DESC, colour
```

This will give you your results, with the most popular colors first.  If you have two colors with the same popularity, then you get those results sorted by color.

Comment: This will give you a syntax error. Analytic functions may not be used in ORDER BY.

Comment: It works on my 11g database.  Perhaps you're thinking of the WHERE clause.

Comment: @mathguy: Have a look in the last sentence of the second paragraph here: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Comment: No, I was thinking about ORDER BY. I stand corrected. (I remembered that not working for me in the past, but I probably remember wrong - it's happened before). This is, then, the right way to do it. +1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right, I would try something like:

```
SELECT C.colour, T1.F1, T1.F2, T2.F3, T2.F4
FROM (
    SELECT colour, COUNT(*) as Popularity FROM tblexampl1
    GROUP BY colour) C
JOIN tblexampl1 T1 ON C.colour = T1.colour
JOIN tblexampl2 T2 on T1.unique_id = T2.unique_id
ORDER BY C.Popularity DESC
```

If Oracle supports WITH you can put the subquery in a WITH clause which is a little bit easier to read.